# Refunding test purchases when testing Google in-App

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I'm having trouble refunding. When i log-in to the publisher console, it shows my purchase and a "Cancel Entire order" button. The "refund some money" button is greyed out. Payment was done using a test-account. The app is not yet published. How do i go about getting my money back, and will google still charge me the 30% even if i refund on a test account?

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607152/testing-of-in-app-billing-with-test-accounts/5777952#5777952) But there is no answer on how he did it, is there a way i can PM him about it or ask directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for a day or a few - button will appear after that (when transaction happens on user's card, the amount is put on hold, the real transaction happens later - looks like button is enabled only after that).

Comment: Is it the "refund some money" button? My product is unmanaged type, does that make any difference. My credit card has already been charged. [Image](http://marketbilling.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=4799813451489061708&name=in-app-billing-no-refund.png&token=3ce0d425401ab102a9faf961f4305b77&inline=1) Thanks

Comment: Not sure about exact button name (my google checkout interface is in RU). My product was managed type, but believe there will not be any difference. Just wait a few more days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the account owner, then proceed with below steps.

```
Sign in to your Play Console.
On the left menu, select Order management.
Select the orders you’d like to refund.
    To find a specific order, search by order ID or a user’s full email address.
    To refund multiple orders at the same time, make sure you only select orders made by one user.
Click Refund.
Select the appropriate refund reason.
Click Submit.
    If the Submit button isn’t available, the order has already been refunded.
```