# Is there a way to forbid users from refunding in-app product

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Right now I have my app set up so when the user completes a purchase, a TextView appears with a link to a Google Doc.  If the user then cancels their purchase and gets a refund, they can easily just have downloaded and saved the Google Doc before refunding, correct?

If I am looking at this wrong, please correct me.  If not, what can I do to solve this?  Can I take away the option to refund this purchase?  Is there a better way to go about providing a user with a .doc file after a purchase?  I am asking this because since releasing the latest version of my app with this in-app purchase, I have seen all 4 purchases be refunded so far.

Example below of a "cancelled order":

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using In-App Purchase? According to this document, no refunds are allowed. https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1061913?hl=en-gb

Comment: check this link it will help you.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607152/testing-of-in-app-billing-with-test-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Make your app free, and have the option to get the Google Doc available as an in-app purchase.

From ["In-App Purchase Policy"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1061913?hl=en-gb):

> In-app purchases are different than other Android app purchases on
>   Google Play in two ways:
>
> - There is **no** 15-minute refund period - all refunds are at the discretion of the developer
> - Restoring in-app purchases are the responsibility of the developer

Comment: That is what I have already done.  My question is how do I forbid them for cancelling/refunding their in-app purchase after purchasing the Google Doc?

Comment: Simply don't allow it! It says "all refunds are at the discretion of the developer." That's you. You can allow or disallow it as you wish.

Comment: Look at the picture I just added to my opening post.  It gives no reason for the cancellation and I did not allow it.  I have gotten 4 or 5 of these now that just say the reason is "Other."

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is charging the user to download the app from the store. This purchase can be refunded within 15 minutes.

If you implement an in app purchase, as in the user downloads the app free, and there is a purchase button inside the app to reveal the download, then they cannot get a refund for that.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure that user will be able to download the full file after the refund period (15 minutes) will pass. Before that he should be able to download some sample file to decide if he want to get refund or not. You cannot just disable refund option, even if this would be possible it would be definitely bad practice...

Comment: -1. ["There is **no** 15-minute refund period - all refunds are at the discretion of the developer"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1061913?hl=en-gb) - emphasis not even mine.

Comment: That's an application, not an in-app purchase.

Comment: I agree with @WChargin.  This 15 minute period does not refer to in-app purchases.

Comment: Yeah. All the applications have 15 minutes refund period and this topic is about buying application not in-app purchase. So down-voting here is not appropriate.

Comment: "releasing the latest version of my app with this **in-app purchase**" (emphasis mine) it looks like in-app purchase to me

Comment: So users apply for refund for a file or application? I didn't notice that. Then you are right, he can just forbid them to get refund for the in-app purchase.

Comment: Yea this is about an in-app purchase inside a free app.  This question is not about buying a paid app.  So there is an option to forbid them to get a refund for a in-app purchase?  How/where is that?

Comment: Well, maybe you will find something interesting here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html